# Como insertar datos en una tabla relacionada

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy insertando datos en la tabla equipos, pero primero tengo que agregar los modelos, `tipos`, `clasesy`marcas`, para después llamarlos por medio del`Id` a la tabla equipo.

hago este procedimiento actualmente

```
INSERT INTO `equipments` (`id`, `number_serie`, `brand_id`, `model_id`, `type_piece_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `equipment_class_id`, `equipment_type_id`, `deleted_at`, `notes_add`) 
 VALUES (NULL, 'RY45FE4RF', '1', '1', '1', '20', '2019-02-01 00:00:00', '2019-02-01 00:00:00', '1', '1', NULL, 'Sin fallas');
```

Como le haría para agregar los datos y si no existe esa marca, modelo, tipo o clase que lo agregue en su respectiva tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a que te referis con script? donde estas ejecutando eso?

Comment: en leguaje sql, lo estoy ejecutando en xammp

Comment: Entonces no es un script, es una consulta comun y corriente. Vos queres hacer un procedimiento almacenado completo entonces? o sea, toda una funcion que haga lo que vos pedis?

Comment: si, quiero insertar datos sin la necesidad de estar agregando uno por uno.

Comment: pero no en una tabla.. en todas?.. la respuesta es no, cada insert se hace a la tabla que corresponde...

Comment: En general estas cosas las hace un sistema.. o sea.. vos no usas directamente tu db.. o si?

Comment: ahh ya, por el momento si, es pura base de datos, y pues un poco tedioso estar creando primero las marcas,etc. y despues llamarlos en la tabla equipos

Comment: y eso va a hacer la persona que use tu sistema. Tendra una pantalla para cargar las marcas, otra para los modelos.. y cada una de esas generara un insert a la tabla que corresponda... y no es tedioso.. es programacion ;)

Comment: gracias, ni modo por el momento tentré que crear una por una mis datos